Create DXGISwapChain for selectively rendering content of Child HWND (multiple tabs)
I am trying to improve the performance of my application by rendering using DXGISwapChain . My application supports multiple tab views just like chrome and has other views present as well which are sibling of these tabs. I want to render only the contents of TabViews using DXGI.
I also don't want to get into overhead of creating multiple swapchains for each tab hwnd because the number of tabs can exceed 100.
Is there a way to achieve this?
There are some viewports related calls ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetViewports . These don't seem to be related though, it seems it will take all the viewports and render them . Has anyone encountered this problem before?

A swapchain is a set (minimum 2) of buffer/surface/texture and  you can render whatever you want on it, whenever you want. You can render each tabview on a unique swapchain everytime a tabview is switched on. What's your question exactly?

Thanks @SimonMourier for replying.  I want to skip creating multiple swapchain for each tab view. Rather, create a swapchain on the application window which will be common to all tabviews and selectively render the content of the tabviews using swapchain . For all other sibling views, draw using their normal gdi workflow since they are mostly static (buttons) . Is it possible to achieve this

There's nothing builtin if that's your question, and GDI interop with swapchain doesn't allow everything, you'll have to use Direct2D https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-gdi-interoperation-overview ie: depends on your code, not an easy work
